# How to find the way detect if item have been drag

Tags: jquery

I'm using this [plugin](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/)
 make div can be drag and sort, how to find the way  detect if one of `.list` have been drag then do something?
I tried if mousedown on `.list` then do something but there's another div inside `.list` and it have to be click and not in mousedown statement

```
$(".wrap").sortable();
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="list"><div class="button"></div></div>
    <div class="list"></div>
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use start, stop events. See documentation here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start

Answer (score 0):

`bind sortupdate` event handler like this (Updated):

```
$(".wrap").sortable().bind('sortupdate', function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```